# How to deal with multiple newly Added Entities that depend on each otter with a Foreign key constraint - EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had a bit of difficulties with getting the right title for this problem so I hope my explanation below will make it a bit clearer.

I am using `EntityFramework 6` and I am doing multiple inserts within a function.

There are 3 different tables which get updated / inserted: table `EntityMethod`, `EntityRoom` and `EntityRoomMethod`. The table `EntityRoomMethod` has a `foreign key` relationship with the table `EntityMethod`.

In some cases, a `EntityMethod` row is missing and this is newly created by adding the object with entity framework:

```
if (mn == null)
{
    mn = new Method
    {
        ElementId = floorProgram.ElementId,
        ActionId = m.ActionId,
        ElementCount = m.ElementCount,
        ColorId = m.ColorId,
        IsBase = m.IsBase,
        IsHccp = m.IsHccp,
        TimeNorm = m.TimeNorm,
        Frequency5Id = m.Frequency5Id,
        MaterialId = m.MaterialId,
        ProductId = m.ProductId,
        MethodTypeId = m.MethodTypeId,
    };
}
```

In another part of code the `Method foreign key (MethodId)` of the `EntityRoomMethod` table is being set:

```
roomMethodObject.RightId = mn.Id;
```

`RightId`  is in this case the relationship with the `EntityMethod` table.

On a later point the other 2 table objects (`EntityRoom` and `EntityRoomMethod`) are also added (`DBSet.Add`) using EF.

The problem however is, that when the `EntityMethod` is **newly** added, it gets the `Id` value of **0**, because `SaveChanges()` is not yet executed. The foreign key reference in the `EntityRoomMethod` is therefor also being set to **0**.

When the function returns to the caller, the `SaveChanges()` is being executed and all 3 objects (representing the 3 tables) are being saved. 
This however will generate a FK error (because Id 0 does not exist obviously).

I tried to fix this by calling `SaveChanges()` after Adding the new Method (so directly in the function). This however will cause some other problems. 
In the end I have gotten multiple errors but I assume it all has to do with the same thing, the errors were the following:

1. Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Solution.Data.RoomMethod_Method' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
2. The property 'RightId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
3. Conflicting changes to the role x of the relationship y have been detected

So now the actual question:
Is there an (easy) way to call `SaveChanges()` after all 3 entities have been added with EF but also handling the FK errors? Does this mean I have to generate the Id's myself? Or was the first approach better (Calling `SaveChanges` directly after adding the `EntityMethod` object).

For now I have some not-nice-looking solution with doing a direct `INSERT` statement after adding a new `EntityMethod` (using `Dapper`). This kind-of works but I assume there is a better way wherein I can just use EF6.

P.S. calling `SaveChanges()` after adding the `EntityMethod` was basically the same by doing it with `Dapper`, however this generated some other errors while using `Dapper` it didn't generate those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap several `SaveChanges` within a transaction, and EF (or probably SQL) will generate the required ids at each point, allowing you to reference them later on.

```
using(var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   var p1 = new Something { Name = "Fred" };
   _context.SaveChanges();

   var a2 = new Dependency { SomethingId = p1.Id }; <-- p1.Id now has an Id value
   _context.SaveChanges();

   var b3 = new OtherDependency { DependencyId = a2.Id };  <-- a2.Id now has an Id value
   _context.SaveChanges();

  transaction.Commit(); <-- All 3 changes are fully committed to the db at this point.
}
```

Comment: Could you give a small example, should I wrap each object that is being added or updated in a `SaveChanges` transaction? So with my example this means 3 transaction with 3 `SaveChanges`, does this return Id's while they are not being inserted yet? Or should I wrap / use a single `SaveChanges` (like it is done now) which updates/inserts all 3 objects within a transaction? With the latter I would not be able to set some `Foreign Key` value of another entity right (since the setting of the foreign key happens before the `SaveChanges` so the FK Id should be known earlier?